# How do I wait until all the Promises are fulfilled in RxJS?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have a list of Promises that I want to get the result and display on the page.

```
 let directives = ['object-src', 'img-src', 'media-src', 'script-src', 'style-src', 'frame-src', 'child-src'];

 let directivesStream = Rx.Observable.from(directives)
   .map((d) => {
     let q = getSummaryCSP({
       origin: origin,
         directive: d,
         from: moment().subtract(3, 'days').utc().format(),
         to: moment().utc().format()
     });

     return Rx.Observable.interval(10000)
       .flatMap(() => Rx.Observable.fromPromise(queries.query(q)));
   });

 directivesStream.mergeAll().subscribe((response) => {
   let flattenedRes = _.sortBy(response.data, (e) => e.event.count);
   flattenedRes = _.reverse(flattenedRes);
   this.setState({
     cspReport: flattenedRes
   });
 });
```

So what it's doing is it creates a stream of Promises with interval of `10000`. However, the end result is the combined results of all the promises that's why I'm doing `sorting` and `reversing` and then display the result in React.

I know that everything in RxJs is a stream. So, I'm not sure if I can achieve this at all?

So, my question is how do I create a stream of Promises that at the end 10s, all the streams have to be merged into one stream so I can use the result of all the promises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question well, but here are a few pointers for you to investigate:

- [`toArray`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/toarray.md) operator : allow to gather all emissions of a streams into an array
- [`forkJoin`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/forkjoin.md) operator : equivalent to `Promise.all`, runs all promises in parallel and gather all results

I am confident that with one of those two you can achieve your goal. I let you figure out which as trying to solve a problem by oneself is the best way to get a good understanding of Rxjs. You can in addition find a list of operators [here](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/categories.md). I recommend you to have a look before posting a question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I know what's wrong. I need to use forkJoin instead of fromPromise.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can import node modules into your client side code in React, I would take a look at the [Async](https://github.com/caolan/async) node module. I believe the execution process you want to happen is a combination of map and waterfall.

```
async.waterfall([
    myFirstFunction,
    mySecondFunction,
    myLastFunction,
], function (err, result) {
    // result now equals 'done'
});
function myFirstFunction(callback) {
    callback(null, 'one', 'two');
}
function mySecondFunction(arg1, arg2, callback) {
    // arg1 now equals 'one' and arg2 now equals 'two'
    callback(null, 'three');
}
function myLastFunction(arg1, callback) {
    // arg1 now equals 'three'
    callback(null, 'done');
}
```

Comment: Would i be able to use that with RxJs?

Comment: Waterfall from async.js could be to implemented pretty easy with Rx http://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/mappingr_rxjs_from_different_libraries/async/index.html#asyncwaterfall

Comment: If you want to save ordering of your promises you can use `concatMap`, `concatAll` or `concat` If you have smth like recursive promises you can use `expand` operator